# Extract Data From A URL Using Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to extract data from a URL that is in a single cell in google sheets. The data in the cell is:

```
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/2017-SKMEI-Outdoor-Sports-Compass-Watches-Hiking-Men-Watch-Digital-LED-Electronic-Watch-Man-Sports-Watches/32790079639.html?spm=a2g01.8286187.3.1.3fa025c4ONMmXB&scm=1007.14594.99248.0&scm_id=1007.14594.99248.0&scm-url=1007.14594.99248.0&pvid=bff55205-e331-4c05-9e04-6e8c1a660f0f
```

From the URL I need to extract the number: **32790079639**

Is there a way collecting this information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"([^/]*)\.html")`

A1 is text with your URL.

- `[^/]*` -- any text, not /,
- `(...)` -- to capture gruop

Comment: You'll want to escape the `.` in your expression; By default, `.` matches any character that's not newline

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [`=REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244) to achieve this goal. This function uses a regular expression to extract a substring from the input. For example,

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "([0-9]+)\.html")
```

A full example [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ARlV89j3y3HlpQKW3YygrLhrCcalS4GiHsnbM1xnLG0/edit#gid=0)